# upper bound for a negative function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x\in (-\infty,2).$ Is it possible to get a bound for $$f(x):=\big(1+\frac{1}{2-x}\big)^{-1/4}-1\;?$$

It seems difficult, I find that $f(x)$ is negative, I tried using MVT but no sucess.

Perhaps it is not possible, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite $f(x)$ as
$$
 f(x) = \left(\frac{3-x}{2-x}\right)^{-1/4}-1 = \left(\frac{2-x}{3-x}\right)^{1/4}-1
= \left(1- \frac{1}{3-x}\right)^{1/4}-1
$$
and conclude that $-1 < f(x) < 0$. This are the best possible bounds on the interval, as can be seen by considering $x \to 2$ and $x \to -\infty$.

If the goal is to get “simpler function” as an upper bound which is still strictly negative, then you could use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality):
$$
f(x) \le 1 - \frac 14 \cdot \frac{1}{3-x} - 1 = -\frac{1}{4(3-x)} < 0\, .
$$

Comment: I already notice that $f$ is negative. But we can perhaps bound $f$ by another function, no ?

Comment: @TTL: What kind of estimate are you looking for? Bernoulli's inequality gives $f(x) \le -\frac{1}{4(3-x)}$, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$f'(x)=-\frac{\left(\frac{x-3}{x-2}\right)^\frac34}{4(x-3)^2}<0$$

therefore $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing and $-1<f(x)<0$.